# How to test the component when we are using react query lib it is asking queryclient

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chai

```
 While adding test for am facing this particular issue can someone please help me to resolve this issue , just want to know how to set queryclient inside register page it self
```

**Register.jsx** ---Main page which is user registration trying to dom testing for this

```
   /* eslint-disable no-console */
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Form, Input, Button, Checkbox, Divider } from 'antd';
import {
  UserOutlined,
  LockOutlined,
  MailOutlined,
} from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useMutation } from 'react-query';
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

import { func } from 'prop-types';
import { registerUser } from '../../api/auth.api';

const Register = ({ t }) => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [isMailInUse, setIsMailInUse] = useState(false);
  const {
    mutate,
    isSuccess,
    isError,
    isLoading,
    error,
  } = useMutation(registerUser);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isError && error.response.status === 409) {
      setIsMailInUse(true);
      form.validateFields();
    }
  }, [isError, error, form]);

  const onFinish = (inputs) => {
    // console.log('Received values of form: ', inputs);
    mutate(inputs);
  };

  if (isSuccess) {
    return <Redirect to="/Dashboard" />;
  }

  return (
    <Form
      form={form}
      name="normal_login"
      className="login-form"
      initialValues={{
        remember: true,
      }}
      onFinish={onFinish}
    >
      <Form.Item
        name="fullname"
        data-testid="fullname"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: t('form_errors.enter_full_name'),
          },
          {
            min: 4,
            message: t('form_errors.name_atleast_four_chars'),
          },
          {
            max: 20,
            message: t('form_errors.name_max_twenty_chars'),
          },
          {
            pattern: new RegExp(
              /^[A-Za-z\s]{1,}[.]{0,1}[A-Za-z\s]{0,}$/,
            ),
            message: t('form_errors.valid_name'),
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input
          type="text"
          data-testid="username"
          prefix={<UserOutlined className="site-form-item-icon" />}
          placeholder={t('name')}
        />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item
        name="email"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: t('form_errors.email_required'),
          },
          {
            pattern: new RegExp(
              /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/,
            ),
            message: t('form_errors.valid_email_id'),
          },
          {
            validator: () =>
              !isMailInUse
                ? Promise.resolve()
                : Promise.reject(new Error(t('errors.email_in_use'))),
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input
          type="email"
          onChange={() =>
            isMailInUse ? setIsMailInUse(false) : null
          }
          prefix={<MailOutlined className="site-form-item-icon" />}
          placeholder={t('email')}
        />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item
        name="password"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: t('form_errors.password_not_found'),
          },
          {
            min: 8,
            message: t('form_errors.password_min_eight_chars'),
          },
        ]}
        hasFeedback
      >
        <Input.Password
          prefix={<LockOutlined className="site-form-item-icon" />}
          type="password"
          autoComplete="new-password"
          placeholder={t('password')}
        />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item
        name="confirmpassword"
        dependencies={['password']}
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: t('form_errors.password_confirmation'),
          },
          ({ getFieldValue }) => ({
            validator(_, value) {
              if (!value || getFieldValue('password') === value) {
                return Promise.resolve();
              }
              return Promise.reject(
                new Error(t('errors.passwords_do_not_match')),
              );
            },
          }),
        ]}
        hasFeedback
      >
        <Input.Password
          prefix={<LockOutlined className="site-form-item-icon" />}
          type="password"
          autoComplete="new-password"
          placeholder={t('tasks.confirm_password')}
        />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item>
        <Form.Item name="remember" valuePropName="checked" noStyle>
          <Checkbox>{t('tasks.remember_me')}</Checkbox>
        </Form.Item>

        <Link
          className="login-form-forgot"
          style={{ float: 'right' }}
          to="#/something"
        >
          {t('forgot_password')}
        </Link>
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item>
        <Button
          type="primary"
          loading={isLoading}
          htmlType="submit"
          className="login-form-button"
        >
          {t('tasks.register')}
        </Button>
        {'\n'}
        Or
        {'\n'}
        <Button
          type="ghost"
          htmlType="submit"
          className="login-form-button"
          onClick={() =>
            window.open(
              'http://api.realdev.in/oauth/redirect/github',
              '_self',
            )
          }
        >
          {t('tasks.login_with_github')}
        </Button>
        <Divider plain>OR</Divider>

            <Link to="/login"> {t('tasks.login_now')}</Link>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      );
    };
    
    Register.propTypes = {
      t: func.isRequired,
    };
    
    export default withTranslation()(Register);
```

-- Main component which get loaded on page render ,here I have added queryclient for reactquery usage
App.jsx

```
     import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { func, shape } from 'prop-types';
import { Row, Col, Typography, Tabs } from 'antd';
import '../css/form.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';

import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import { QueryClientProvider, QueryClient } from 'react-query';
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from 'react-query/devtools';
import Login from './Authentication/Login';
import Register from './Authentication/Register';
import OAuth from './Authentication/OAuth';
import GithubAuth from './Authentication/GithubAuth';
import Dashboard from './Authentication/Dashboard';
import Error from './Authentication/Error';

const { TabPane } = Tabs;
// import StoreDemo from './StoreDemo';
//
const queryClient = new QueryClient();

const App = ({ t, i18n }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    i18n.changeLanguage('en');
  }, [i18n]);
  const { Text, Title } = Typography;

  return (
    <>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/oauth">
              <OAuth />
            </Route>

            <Route path="/projects">
              <h2>Projects</h2>
            </Route>

            <Route path="/Dashboard">
              <Dashboard />
            </Route>

            <Route path="/Error">
              <Error />
            </Route>

            <Route
              path="/:route"
              render={({ match, history }) => {
                if (
                  match.params.route === 'login' ||
                  match.params.route === 'register'
                ) {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <div className="form--wrapper">
                        <Row>
                          <Col span={24} offset={0}>
                            <Title className="site--logo">
                              {t('easy_collab')}
                            </Title>
                            <div className="form--container">
                              <Title level={3}>
                                {t('tasks.login_to_easycollab')}
                              </Title>
                              <Text type="secondary">
                                {t('tasks.continue_with_email')}
                              </Text>
                              <br />
                              <br />
                              <Switch>
                                <>
                                  <Tabs
                                    activeKey={match.params.route}
                                    onChange={(route) => {
                                      history.push(`/${route}`);
                                    }}
                                  >
                                    <TabPane tab="Login" key="login">
                                      <Helmet>
                                        <title>
                                          {t('tasks.login')} •{' '}
                                          {t('easy_collab')}
                                        </title>
                                      </Helmet>
                                      <Login />
                                    </TabPane>
                                    <TabPane
                                      tab="Register"
                                      key="register"
                                    >
                                      <Helmet>
                                        <title>
                                          {t('tasks.register')} •{' '}
                                          {t('easy_collab')}
                                        </title>
                                      </Helmet>
                                      <Register />
                                    </TabPane>
                                  </Tabs>
                                </>
                              </Switch>
                            </div>
                          </Col>
                        </Row>
                      </div>
                    </>
                  );
                }
                return null;
              }}
            />
            <Route path="/login/github" exact>
              <GithubAuth />
            </Route>

            <Route path="/" exact>
              <Helmet>
                <title />
                {t('home')} • {t('easy_collab')}
              </Helmet>
              {t('errors.unauthorized_access')}
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
        <ReactQueryDevtools />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </>
  );
};

App.propTypes = {
  t: func.isRequired,
  i18n: shape({ changeLanguage: func }).isRequired,
};

export default withTranslation()(App);
```

**Register.test.jsx**

```
    import React from 'react';
import {
  render,
  fireEvent,
  findByText,
} from '@testing-library/react';
import { expect } from 'chai';

import '../i18n/index';
import Register from '../components/Authentication/Register';
import App from '../components/App';

describe('App', () => {
  it('renders App component', async () => {
    const { getByTestId, container } = render(<Register />);
    const usernameEl = getByTestId('username');
    // const nameEl = getByTestId('fullname');
    fireEvent.change(usernameEl, {
      target: {
        value: 'po',
      },
    });
    expect(
      await findByText(
        container,
        'Name must be atleast 4 characters',
      ),
    ).toBeVisible();
  });
});
```

**Error facing**

```
          Browser logs:
      Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one
        at useQueryClient (_snowpack\pkg\common\QueryClientProvider-dd42f785.js:27:11)
        at useMutation (_snowpack\pkg\react-query.js:3092:21)
        at Register (dist\components\Authentication\Register.js:22:7)
        at renderWithHooks (_snowpack\pkg\common\index-163c0f63.js:16160:18)
        at mountIndeterminateComponent (_snowpack\pkg\common\index-163c0f63.js:18986:13)
        at beginWork (_snowpack\pkg\common\index-163c0f63.js:20224:16)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (_snowpack\pkg\common\index-163c0f63.js:5123:14)
        at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (_snowpack\pkg\common\index-163c0f63.js:5172:16)
        at invokeGuardedCallback (_snowpack\pkg\common\index-163c0f63.js:5234:31)
        at beginWork$1 (_snowpack\pkg\common\index-163c0f63.js:25128:7)
      Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one
        at useQueryClient (_snowpack\pkg\common\QueryClientProvider-dd42f785.js:27:11)
        at useMutation (_snowpack\pkg\react-query.js:3092:21)
        at Register (dist\components\Authentication\Register.js:22:7)
        at renderWithHooks (_snowpack\pkg\common\index-163c0f63.js:16160:18)
        at mountIndeterminateComponent (_snowpack\pkg\common\index-163c0f63.js:18986:13)
        at beginWork (_snowpack\pkg\common\index-163c0f63.js:20224:16)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (_snowpack\pkg\common\index-163c0f63.js:5123:14)
        at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (_snowpack\pkg\common\index-163c0f63.js:5172:16)
        at invokeGuardedCallback (_snowpack\pkg\common\index-163c0f63.js:5234:31)
        at beginWork$1 (_snowpack\pkg\common\index-163c0f63.js:25128:7)
      The above error occurred in the <Register> component:

          at Register (http://localhost:8000/dist/components/Authentication/Register.js:13:20)
          at withI18nextTranslation(Register) (http://localhost:8000/_snowpack/pkg/react-i18next.js:918:31)

      Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
      Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
      Error: done() called multiple times in test <App renders App component>; in addition, done() received error: Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one
        at createMultipleDoneError (..\..\D:\Opensource\easy-collab-frontend\node_modules\@web\test-runner-mocha\dist\autorun.js:1:242101)
        at ..\..\D:\Opensource\easy-collab-frontend\node_modules\@web\test-runner-mocha\dist\autorun.js:1:254722
        at a (..\..\D:\Opensource\easy-collab-frontend\node_modules\@web\test-runner-mocha\dist\autorun.js:1:254732)
        at ..\..\D:\Opensource\easy-collab-frontend\node_modules\@web\test-runner-mocha\dist\autorun.js:1:255788

 ❌ App > renders App component
      Error: Uncaught Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one (http://localhost:8000/_snowpack/pkg/common/QueryClientProvider-dd42f785.js:27)
        at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (_snowpack\pkg\common\index-163c0f63.js:5172:16)
        at invokeGuardedCallback (_snowpack\pkg\common\index-163c0f63.js:5234:31)
        at beginWork$1 (_snowpack\pkg\common\index-163c0f63.js:25128:7)
        at performUnitOfWork (_snowpack\pkg\common\index-163c0f63.js:23943:12)
        at workLoopSync (_snowpack\pkg\common\index-163c0f63.js:23871:5)
        at renderRootSync (_snowpack\pkg\common\index-163c0f63.js:23834:7)
        at performSyncWorkOnRoot (_snowpack\pkg\common\index-163c0f63.js:23457:18)
        at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (_snowpack\pkg\common\index-163c0f63.js:23045:7)
        at updateContainer (_snowpack\pkg\common\index-163c0f63.js:26646:3)

Chrome: |██████████████████████████████| 2/2 test files | 1 passed, 1 failed

Code coverage: 48.42 %
View full coverage report at coverage\lcov-report\index.html

Finished running tests in 19.1s with 1 failed tests.
```

Trying get resolve this issue am getting error like this, if anyone faced or can help me with this please answer to my query

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing

Answer (score 1):

From the error, you're missing the `QueryProvider.`

1. Create a new client. It's useful to have set it not to retry:

```
const cleanClient = new QueryClient(
  {
    defaultOptions: {
      queries: {
        retry: false,
      },
    },
  });
```

2. Create a a wrapper component:

```
const QueryProviderWrapper = ({ children }: { children: ReactElement}): ReactElement<QueryClientProviderProps> => {
  return (
      <QueryClientProvider client={client}>{children}</QueryClientProvider>
  );
};
```

3. Modify your render:

```
const { getByTestId, container } = render(
  <QueryProviderWrapper client={cleanClient}>
    <Register />
  </QueryProviderWrapper>
);
```

4. Depending on your tests, you may want to **clear** that client; this is the example for it:

```
afterEach(() => {
    cleanClient.clear();
  });
```